# Python no error when trying to open some integers or True as a file

Tags: python, io

On Python 3.8.5, I'd have expected code like this to give an error:

```py
open(1, 'w').close()
```

but it doesn't. More Interestingly, if I run it twice then I do see an error:

```
>>> open(1, 'w').close()
>>> open(1, 'w').close()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Can someone explain what is happening here? I suspect it has something to do with the fact that `open` can take a bytes object as the `file` argument, but why is the error only registered the second time I feed an invalid `file` argument?

Interestingly: `True` also exhibits the same behavior (not `False`), as do some integers. Others, like `2`, allow me to run `open(2, 'w').close()` several times. Others, like 100, give an error right away.

**EDIT:** As noted in the comments, the reason seems to be that integers are interpreted as [file descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations).

Comment: I am not able to re-produce the issue.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Do you get an error message? If so, what is the message?

Comment: No, tested with `open(1, 'w').close()` multiple times.

Comment: `open` will work with `1` anyway because it's a [file descriptor for stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Thank you for pointing me to the docs. I didn't know. Could you test `open(True, 'w').close()` and let me know if it gives an error or not?